# How to call ifcconvert from the terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, python, pip

I want to convert icf files to objs, to that effect I want to use this tool:
https://ifcopenshell.org/downloads.html

I installed it through python like this:
`pip install ifcopenshell`

However, I am unable to call any of the utilities the tool claims to have. In particular, I cannot do `ifcconvert` from the terminal.

I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: What do you mean "I cannot do ifcconvert from the terminal"? What do you do exactly and what does the computer respond?

Comment: It doesn't show as an available command. There's no auto complete and which does not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Download the zip from [here](https://blenderbim.org/docs-python/ifcconvert/installation.html). Then extract the binary file from the zip and place it is a directory, say `.local/bin` .
Assure the directory is in `PATH`. In order to do that open `.bashrc` file from the home directory. Add the line to end of the file:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

Now open terminal and restart bash: `bash --`

Now type `IfcConvert --help` to check it is working.